# I am confused as to why this question "What is the exact step by step process of Borg assimilation?" was too broad and closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

I asked this currently closed and deleted question, **"[What is the exact step by step process of Borg assimilation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89353/what-is-the-exact-step-by-step-process-of-borg-assimilation) [closed]"** (only visible to 10k+ users; sorry).

I can't figure out for the life of me why this is too broad. It's not like there's 10,000 steps. I clarified the question with specific points of what my confusion is/was and included a quote from wiki about wikis view of assimilation.

**I am asking the community to vote to undelete and reopen the question.** I realize there are very few with the ability/reputation to undelete and reopen questions and those with the ability generally tend to do the opposite, but I'd still like to see the question undeleted and reopened.

If you were one of the people who voted to close the question I'd like an explanation of why so I can edit it to make it less broad. I was told that Meta is the place to go with questions/requests like this.

---

#### For <10k rep users, here's the full text of the question:

We were having this discussion in some comment lines, so I thought I'd throw this question out there. Hopefully the others commentators will chime in on this.

I did do some research on this.

From [the Wikipedia article on the Borg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29#Assimilation):

> The method of assimilating individual life-forms into the collective has been represented differently over time. The only constant is that the infant, and fetal humanoids have been grown in an accelerated state and surgically receive implants connected directly into the brain (cannot be removed without death), as well as ocular devices, tool-enhanced limbs, armor, and other prosthetics. In Star Trek: First Contact, the method of adult assimilation is depicted with the more efficient injection of nanoprobes into the individual's bloodstream through a pair of tubules that spring forth from the drone's hand. Assimilation by tubules is depicted on-screen as being a fast-acting process, with the victim's skin pigmentation turning gray with visible dark tracks forming within moments of contact. The individual is then taken away for complete assimilation by drones. The Borg are neither male nor female and individual's reproductive systems are removed during the process of assimilation. The individual has all traces of individuality removed and implants are attached to the new drone so it can become an integrated part of the collective. This method of assimilation is also shown to be much more surgical in nature. In Star Trek: First Contact a captured crew member is shown to have a forearm and an eye physically removed and replaced with cybernetic implants.

Wiki has more, but that's enough to explain my confusion.

So here are the main parts that I'm concerned about in terms of this question:

1. What is involved step by step in assimilating an individual?
2. Are nanites required at all, a necessary step, or just one of several ways to get to create a drone.
3. Are prosthetics and implants required at all, a necessary step, or just one of several ways to create a drone?

What is the step by step process, and if there is more than one process please describe as many as you know of to get from an individual to a fully matured Borg drone.

On a side note, do they really remove the reproductive organs? 7 of 9 didn't have female sex organs? Picard's were removed? Hugh's manhood was taken from him?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't (vote to) close it, but I can easily see why people would.

1) In your question you posed no less than 8 separate questions. In and of itself, this makes it too broad to effectively answer.

2) It probably didn't help that you also made disparaging remarks at the bottom of the question to discourage people from actively editing the question to make it better:

> - What is involved step by step in assimilating an individual?
> - Are nanites required at all, a necessary step, or just one of several ways to get to create a drone.
> - Are prosthetics and implants required at all, a necessary step, or just one of several ways to create a drone?
> - What is the step by step process, and if there is more than one process please describe as many as you know of to get from an
>     individual to a fully matured Borg drone.
> - Do they really remove the reproductive organs?
> - 7 of 9 didn't have female sex organs?
> - Picard's [sex organs] were removed?
> - Hugh's manhood was taken from him?

Comment: I only "disparaged" 1 individual who was constantly doing bad edits that were not necessarily grammatically correct. This time he did it again & even edited out a quote from an article which is a definite no no. You can add a <sic> if you want but I was agitated & wanted him to stop, for the most part it was effective & he did. As for the 8 questions, it was one question. I can easily change those to "thoughts to consider." I have been doing that more recently as it's sometimes nit picky here on writing style rather than content. If I change the 8 to statements will you reopen?

Comment: @JMFB - I won't. It's not considered appropriate for moderators to defy the will of the community unless there's an overriding reason to do so.

Comment: it's not really the will of the community. It's what, five people that have to have a reputation over 3000, right? That's hardly a sampling of the overall community. If it were I'd have -2000 reputation instead of +2000. In any event it won't be possible to get the votes. Its a shame because I thought it was a good question and I wanted to understand it better from others who might have other/better resources.

Comment: That's not really eight questions. That's basically two questions (required or optional steps for assimilation, and assimilation & sex organs). A question is not limited to a single question mark...

Comment: @cde - Fair enough. Even if you're generous, it's still one question too many :-)

Comment: @JMFB on the Stack Exchange network, "the community" essentially *means* the high-rep users. By the time you have accumulated enough rep to VTC/VTRO, it is assumed that you understand the scope of the site well enough to do so intelligently. Getting 5 of us to agree on *anything* is difficult enough that 5 close votes is practically a unanimous decision.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - Indeed. And when you can rope enough users together to undo a close vote, that's clearly time for a bit of a conflab.

Comment: Put it this way, if I had seen this before it got deleted, I'd vote to reopen.